# Silverlight - C# Global.asax code first

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, ef-code-first

When creating a MVC code first application, you needed to place the following line in your global.asax file

```
Database.SetInitializer<DBNAME>(new DBNAMEInitializer());
```

I now want to do the same with a Silverlight Navigation Application... Where can I place that line then?

Comment: You don't. Connecting to the database is done via WCF or better still RIA Domain Services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same place. Then you create a WCF service to expose the data and a service proxy in a Silverlight application.